# Pointing my domain to a php application in wamp

Tags: php, apache

I have WAMP installed in a machine and I have only one application in the www directory. SO I want localhost to point to my application directly.

In short, if I hit the

```
http://localhost/
```

in my browser i want my application to open. I don't want my application url to be like

```
http://localhost/application/
```

Can anyone help me out to do the configuration changes.

Thanks,
Uttam Dutta

Answer (score 2):

Put the files for your application in the directory that your DocumentRoot points to instead of in a subdirectory (called *application* in your example) of that directory.

Comment: As I said i have one application, so your right. I need a solution for  In case i have multiple application and I want to point localhost to a particular application.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43522/how-to-change-the-www-root-directory-on-wampserver) should also be helpful, if you'd prefer to keep your files where they are now and point the DocumentRoot to the files instead.

Also, you may consider making a virtual host for each of your projects. Read about creating virtual hosts for localhost [here](http://cesaric.com/?p=255).